# Redirect a AWS static IP to domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, nameservers

I have deployed a django based website on my AWS lightsail instance. the web address has a port 8000 (:8000). I own a domain on (host =fatcow.com). I have created a hosted zone on AWS and pasted the ns values to my provider(factor)'s Nameservers values.  In the amazon route53, I have created a new record with a simple redirect A ipv4 and entered the resolver IP address value - my web address with port value. it doesn't work.

Also, I have read that the redirect will not work for its with port numbers. I have tried redirecting my domain to the static ip, then created another hosted zone record trying to redirect the static ip to the ip+port value - error pops up saying it is not a valid address.

I currently use the development server provided by django as it is a personal website and currently it will not have a lot of traffic - portfolio website.

Also, on my fatcow.com domain settings, the Nameservers are updated and in the whois values, new Nameservers are seen. I have only added the 4 NS values. AWS also created SOA ip values but I was not able to add them to the domain (Inputs were not taken by fatcow ).

In the NSLookup website, I can see NS values and SOA values which are on the AWS hosted zone but A records show none.

Edit: sorry for the confusion. my domain is [www.chandradhar.com](http://www.chandradhar.com). I'm not a web dev but I'm trying to deploy a django based portfolio website. I have added Amazon Lightsail DNS nameservers to my domain (host=fatcow.com). the web address is :8000 port. Without the port number, the website isn't loading at all. Only with the port number along the static IP, the website loads. 'A' record isn't taking the port number. I did add a SRV record with the port number(in AWS route 53) but still doesn't work. when checked from the website nslookup.io, the nameservers are updated correctly

Comment: Can you share the real domain name? (btw, you probably need to make your website reachable on port 443 (or at least 80) - typically done by running simple nginx or apache reverse proxy on the same machine)

Comment: my domain is www.chandradhar.com and http://65.1.214.100:8002 is the aws ip

Comment: You first need to create a record for www.chandradhar.com (in your AWS dns) which points to 65.1.214.100

Comment: in the AWS route 53 hosted zone, I created a SRV record where I added my IP address and the port number.  Earlier,I tried to add a A record but that only takes ip but not the port number.

Comment: Correct, you need `A` record, without port (only ip address)

Comment: Tried that.. waited for a day for the NS update but still did not work. So I removed it and added an SRV record. Also tried having both A and SRV records. still did not work.

Comment: Can you add it again now?

Comment: The A records are updated and I can see them in the nslookup.io website. Also, when I try to go to my website, still the same issue but when I try chandradhar.com, it doesn't work but when I try the URL www.chandradhar.com:8000 it works. At least a step in the right direction.  The only step remaining is to get rid of the port number in the URL. thanks @dusan

Comment: Now you need to make your website reachable on port 443 (or at least 80) - typically done by running simple nginx or apache reverse proxy on the same machine

Comment: It works. I wrote a simple nginx script to listen to the port and a 301 redirect. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to successfully deploy one or more websites on lightsail AWS when the domain is on another website like godaddy/fatcow.

1. Create a dns zone in the networking section of the lightsail instance.
2. Copy the name servers from the dns zone and paste it in the name servers section of the domain provider (fatcow/godaddy) - it might take upto a day for the values to get updated - i used nslookup.io to see if my nameservers were updated.
3. Create 'A' records and SRV records pointing to the static ip of the lightsail instance.
4. Install Nginx
5. Create a simple script with the (name of the website).conf in the conf.d folder/available sites folder
6. Add the following script:

   server
   {
   listen 80;
   server_name domainname.com;
   location / { proxy_pass http://ipAdd:PortNum;
   }
   }
7. Repeat the same code block with different domains and redirect ports. I guess we can also use 301 redirect to achieve the same.

This might or might not be the proper way of achieving what I required but it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Not reproduceable.

```
> host  fatcow.com
fatcow.com has address 65.254.254.33
fatcow.com mail is handled by 10 mail.fatcow.com.
```

Most probably your changes in DNS have already propagated.

Comment: The nameservers are updated but my domain is still not reachable. I think Im making a mistake in setting up the domain redirect to the AWS static IP. I have not setup a A record but a SRV record which redirects to the ip and my 8000 port.

Comment: @Yuri, he owns "domain on fatcow.com", he does not own "domain fatcow.com" :), I also misread first and also checked webpage and was confused

Comment: sorry for the confusion. my domain is www.chandradhar.com. I'm not a web dev but I'm trying to deploy a django based portfolio website. I have added Amazon Lightsail DNS nameservers to my domain (host=fatcow.com). the web address is <ip>:8000 port. Without the port number, the website isn't loading at all. Only with the port number along the static IP, the website loads. 'A' record isn't taking the port number. I did add a SRV record with the port number(in AWS route 53) but still doesn't work. when checked from the website nslookup.io, the nameservers are updated correctly.